# What are best practices for adding Sharepoint Fields,ContentTypes,Lists, etc.?

Tags: sharepoint, oop

For our application, when the site gets installed, it creates a bunch of different fields, lists, content types, etc., etc. There are a lot of dependencies to manage there, and I'm wondering how others go about this, from an OOD perspective.

Answer (score 1):

We use feature stapling to do this kind of work.  For more detail information (and reference application) checkout the Microsoft SharePoint Patterns and Practices.

http://www.codeplex.com/spg